# Updating NuGet Packages on Build Using Mono

Tags: mono, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I wanted to see if there was a way during build to update nuget packages automatically. Has anyone been successful in accomplishing this and if so can you share how you went about this?

Comment: Are you talking about from the cmdline? If so `nuget upgrade` in the root of your solution.

Comment: @SushiHangover - The last time I checked `nuget update` does not work on Mono due to missing implementation in Mono's xbuild.

Comment: I do not know what you mean by that. `nuget` (the shell script wrapper for mono nuget.exe) has nothing to do with `xbuild`. I use `nuget update xxxx.sln` all the time, plus I use the `Nuget.Build.targets` via Mono's `xbuild`  (but that is just shelling to nuget) to create custom build tasks. The only thing that is not available (OS-X/Linux) is Nuget's based shell, which is PowerShell based and not currently available outside Windows...